# Reference SQL scripts in maven dependency using Quarkus Flyway

Tags: java, database-migration, quarkus, flyway

I want Quarkus to execute a flyway migration based on some SQL scripts that I have stored in a separate repository, then packaged into a jar file and published to a private Nexus instance.

I believe I can point to a specific location using this application property:

```
quarkus.flyway.locations=/some/path
```

But given this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myorganisartion.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>myschema</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

What would the value of the flyway.locations property be?

Assume that the folder contains just one folder, containing the .sql files, called myschema.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried googling around and look into quarkus example app, but no luck.

I see that you can reference the classpath in the property value, but I'm not sure what to put after that, and why?

Comment: Have you tried using something like `quarkus.flyway.locations=classpath:db/scripts/migrate.sql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I forgot to reference the datasource:

```
quarkus.flyway.myschema.locations=classpath:myschema/baseline,classpath:myschema/migrations,
```